# Double summation without changing the order of sigmas

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate the following double sum ([from blackpenredpen's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BGxSgSkc2c))
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{m+n}}}$$
In the video, he is showing how to change the order of the sums, but I want to do this normally.

I am pretty confident the inner sum is $\frac{2^m-1}{2^{2m}}$ by geometric series although I am not that good at this subject. Then, how would I evaluate the outer sum?

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{m+n}}=\frac{1}{2^{m}}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{n}}=\frac{2^m-1}{2^{2m}}$$

and then

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^m-1}{2^{2m}}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{m}}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2m}}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{m}}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{m}}$$

and we can use geometric series again.

Comment: oh right, thank you. All the summation "rules" are still new for me.

Comment: @aradarbel10 You did a proper evaluation for the first sum, yu shouldn't have difficulties to obtain the result. You are welcome! Bye